# JQuery in Laravel imported but not working

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am playing around with Laravel last version, trying to import and use JS files on the front-end. I have them stored in my folder 'public/js/'.
I have this Blade template you can see below, pizza.blade.php. If you inspect the page source, you can clearly see the JS files are existing, since their links, which are regularly working, are "http://localhost:8000/storage/...".
Nevertheless, they are not working inside the document and, inspecting the network tab, I can see they are not imported.
The image, pizza.png, located in 'public/storage' is displaying correctly.
What am i doing wrong?
Also, is there a better practice to use JS files, such as mix or npm?
 Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script>src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"</script>
    <script>src="{{ asset('/js/test.js') }}"</script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="ciao">PIZZA LOGO</h1>
    <div>
        <img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/pizza.png" alt="">
    </div>
</body>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".ciao").css('display', 'none');
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error

```
<script>src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"</script>
```

this is just script with single javascript variable and string inside. You need this:

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"></script>
```

this is html script tag with `src` attribute.